# How do I show that $ E(g(X))= \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)f(x)\,dx $?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Given that $X$ is a continuous random variable with pdf $f$, and $g(x)$ is a nonnegative function.

How do I show that 
$$
E(g(X))= \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)f(x)\,dx
$$ 
using the fact that $E(X) = \int_0^\infty P(X>x)\, dx$.

I attempted to prove this by plugging in g(X) into the second equation instead of just X. And then I took the inverse of g to come up with just a cdf of X, then I rewrote the cdf to its equivalent integral form, giving me an expression with double integral. I have no idea how to move on from here.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 5):

I will also assume that you can also use the identity

$$ \mathbb{P}(X \in B) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbf{1}_B(\lambda) f(\lambda) \, d\lambda $$

for any Borel subsets $B$ of $\mathbb{R}$. (In fact, this alone is enough to show the claim in view of our standard machinery, say monotone class theorem. But let us try to utilize the given formula anyhow.)

Using this, we can write

\begin{align*}
E g(X)
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} P(g(X) > x) \, dx \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} P(X \in g^{-1}((x,\infty))) \, dx \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbf{1}_{g^{-1}((x,\infty))}(\lambda) f(\lambda) \, d\lambda \, dx.
\end{align*}

But notice that $\lambda \in g^{-1}((x,\infty))$ holds exactly when $x < g(\lambda)$. So we may replace the indicator function$\mathbf{1}_{g^{-1}((x,\infty))}(\lambda)$ by its equivalent form $\mathbf{1}_{[0, g(\lambda))}(x)$ and then apply the Fubini's theorem to write

\begin{align*}
E g(X) &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbf{1}_{[0, g(\lambda))}(x) f(\lambda) \, d\lambda \, dx \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathbf{1}_{[0, g(\lambda))}(x) f(\lambda) \, \, dx d\lambda \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(\lambda) f(\lambda) \, \, d\lambda.
\end{align*}

---

*Remark.* Notice that your formula

$$ E(X) = \int_{0}^{\infty} P(X > x) \, dx $$

is true for *any* non-negative random variable $X$. This hints that you will certainly need some extra input which are specific to continuous random variables.

Comment: [+1] Very clear

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you for your cheerful comment! :)

Comment: Thank you so much! Your help is very much appreciated. But I am not familiar with the identity you gave. Could there be any other method in which I will only have to use the given itself?

Comment: @user494619, As I mentioned above, your identity $E(X) = \int_{0}^{\infty} P(X > x) \, dx$ is true for any non-negative random variable $X$, which means that you still need a way to relate $P(g(X) > x)$ to the pdf of $X$. But I am not sure which way works best for you as I know nothing about your background on this topic. It seems best if you actually explain your attempt using formulas so we can think about it together.